# Error to create a EntityManager when I add a new @NameQuery customezed

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

I'm working with JPA and I've  Entity and I want to customezed  a NameQuery with     this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM archivoConvenio 
WHERE fechaYHoraFinProceso BETWEEN  DATE('2013-07-01')  AND DATE('2013-07-31')
```

So The @NameQuery is :

```java
 @NamedQuery(name = "ArchivoConvenio.findByPeriodo", query = "SELECT a FROM archivoConvenio a WHERE a.fechaYHoraFinProceso BETWEEN  DATE(:inicio)  AND DATE(:fin)"),
```

I try to get the Information  the following way:

**But now I make a test:**

```java
JpaGenericController<ArchivoConvenio> DAOAC = new JpaGenericController<ArchivoConvenio>(ArchivoConvenio.class);

List<ArchivoConvenio > list = new List<ArchivoConvenio >();
list =(DAOAC.findQuery( "ArchivoConvenio.findByPeriodo",new String[]{"inicio","fin"},
            "2013-07-01","2013-07-31"
            ));
```

Because after these dates will capture and keep the variables  It should be:

```java
 list =(DAOAC.findQuery( "ArchivoConvenio.findByPeriodo",new String[]{"inicio","fin"},
            this.fechaInicioSeleccionada,this.fechaFinalSeleccionada
            ));
```

When `this.fechaInicioSeleccionada,this.fechaFinalSeleccionada` are the type `Date`

Whe I run the application I get next message:

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: ArchivoConvenio.findByPeriodo
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:426)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
... 45 more
```

So,I suppose that :

I'm  doing bad the @Namequery

I'm  doing bad send the query parameters to findQuery

So,someone help me?

What do I'm  doing wrong?

How to fix this mistake?

Thaks!.

**SOLUTION**

The correct @NameQuery:

```
    @NamedQuery(name = "ArchivoConvenio.findByPeriodo", query = "SELECT a FROM ArchivoConvenio  a WHERE a.fechaYHoraFinProceso BETWEEN  :INICIO AND :FIN"),
```

Comment: Not sure, but why are you keeping the `DATE` function if you already pass Date values?

Comment: The first is a test, because after these dates will capture and keep the variables `fechaInicioSeleccionada,fechaFinalSeleccionada`.

Comment: Please don't confuse JSF with JPA. This is just JPA.

Comment: Excuse Me, Yes you have reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity has a name `ArchivoConvenio` according to this `JpaGenericController<ArchivoConvenio>`.
But in the named query you have `archivoConvenio`.
Try to change it to `ArchivoConvenio` because it's case-sensitive.